# Can not open directory even if I sudo user

Tags: sudo

As root user I created a new user in my Ubuntu.

```
adduser isli
```

Than i granted to newly created user sudo permissions

```
usermod -aG sudo isli
```

Than switched to newly created user

```
su isli
```

in my isli user directory have `projects` directory which i want to open

```
sudo ls -al
```

Give the following output

```
drwx------  6 root root  4096 Feb  7 15:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root  4096 Jan 29 06:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Jan 18 09:43 projects
```

But while i am trying `cd projects` the output is `permissions denied` 
What i am doing wrong

Comment: Do `sudo cd projects`. Giving sudo permissions doesn't mean that you can access everything without sudo.

Comment: @Pilot6 even i know that sudo cd isn't proper command because sudo need for programms only. If i type `sudo cd projects` it's return me `sudo: cd: command not found` i think my problem is in another plane

Comment: OK. Then do `sudo -i; cd projects`.

Comment: @Pilot6 isn't worked too

Answer (score 1):

Your user `isli` does not have any permissions for the directory you are in (`.`), which is the parent directory of your `projects` directory. This is because the directory `.` is owned by `root` and others do not have any permissions to it (the last `---` in the mode indicator).

A solution is to give everyone read (`r`) and access (`x`) permissions for the directory:

```
sudo chmod o+rx .
```

Another option which you might prefer is to set the directory to be owned by the user `isli`:

```
sudo chown isli .
```

or if you want to also give `isli` the ownership of everything under that directory (such as the `projects` directory):

```
sudo chown -R isli .
```

(The `-R` switch stand for recursive.) Then `isli` will also be able to edit files in these directories, which you may be what you want.

## Another suggestion

In fact, you might not want to do that, after all: you may be in `root`'s home directory, and you probably want to keep that owned by `root`. The command `su root` did not change the current working directory, so if you started in root's home directory, which is normally `/root`, you would still be there. You probably want to keep that owned by `root`. You can display the current working directory using the command:

```
pwd
```

The solution you are looking for may be to move the `projects` directory into `isli`'s home directory, which is normally `/home/isli`, but if you are not sure about that, you can, in most interactively used shells, refer to it by `~isli`.

To set `isli` as the owner of the `projects` directory, to move it to `isli`'s home directory, and finally to change to that directory, do:

```
sudo chown isli projects
sudo mv projects ~isli/
cd ~isli/projects
```